# Сравнение хэш таблиц

Tags: javascript, hashmap

есть 2 хэш таблицы, состояния за вчера и за сегодня, допускаем, что есть некоторые изменения значений, удаление и добавление новых элементов, как правильно сравнить две такие таблицы, чтобы результат выглядел:

1) список изменившихся элементов
 2) список новых элементов
 3) список удаленных элементов

Пример:

```
let hash1 = {
     "https:/vk.com" : "Любая информация", 
     "https:/twitch.tv" : "Любая информация1", 
     "https:/youtube.com" : "Любая информация 3"
   }
let hash2 = {
     "https:/vk.com" : "Любая информация 1", 
     "https:/youtube.com" : "Любое инфо", 
     "https:/stackoverflow.com", "Любая информация 2"
   }
```

Вот две таблички, на выход хочу получить:
Изменено: `Vk.com`, `Youtube.com`,
Удалено: `Twitch.tv`,
Добавлено: `stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Необходим пример с данными: входными и выходными.

Comment: let hash1 = {"https:/vk.com" : "Любая информация", "https:/twitch.tv" : "Любая информация1", "https:/youtube.com" : "Любая информация 3"}

let hash2 = {"https:/vk.com" : "Любая информация 1", "https:/youtube.com" : "Любое инфо", "https:/stackoverflow.com", "Любая информация 2"}

Вот две таблички, на выход хочу получить: Изменено: Vk.com,Youtube.com , Удалено: Twitch.tv, Добавлено: stackoverflow.com

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1084617/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let obj1 = {
  "https:/vk.com": "Любая информация",
  "https:/twitch.tv": "Любая информация1",
  "https:/youtube.com": "Любая информация 3"
};
let obj2 = {
  "https:/vk.com": "Любая информация 1",
  "https:/youtube.com": "Любое инфо",
  "https:/stackoverflow.com": "Любая информация 2"
}

function checkHash(hash1, hash2) {
  let res = {
    changed: [],
    added: [],
    deleted: []
  };
  const hash1Keys = Object.keys(hash1).sort();
  const hash2Keys = Object.keys(hash2).sort();

  if (hash1Keys.join('') !== hash2Keys.join('')) {
    res = {
      ...res,
      deleted: [
        ...res.deleted,
        hash1Keys.find(item => !hash2Keys.includes(item))
      ]
    }
  }

  return hash2Keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    return !(key in hash1) ? { ...acc,
        added: [...acc.added, key]
      } :
      (hash2[key] !== hash1[key]) ? { ...acc,
        changed: [...acc.changed, key]
      } : acc;
  }, res);
}

const result = checkHash(obj1, obj2);

console.log(`Изменено: ${result.changed.join(', ')}; Удалено: ${result.deleted.join(', ')}; Добавлено: ${result.added.join(', ')}`)
```